# Arg handling in a script for a modified "find" function?

Tags: command-line, shell, shell-script, find, freebsd

I'm using FreeBSD and I understand and use the `-prune` option on `find` to prevent the command descending into a subdirectory. But I find the necessary syntax very clumsy and awkward. It also doesn't prevent the pruned dir itself showing up which is fixable but annoying.

I'd like to create a short script/alias which has the effect of adding a new `-noenter` arg to the `find` command **if** it's given before any other primaries (for simplicity).

The aim is that I can type either of:

- `find -xs /dir -noenter '$*' -name '*.conf' -ls`
- `find -x -s /dir -noenter '$*' -name '*.conf' -ls`

and it'll convert the args and execute:

- `/usr/bin/find -xs /dir \( -name '$*' -prune -or \( -name '*.conf' -and ! \( -type d -and -name '$*' \) \) \) -ls`
- `/usr/bin/find -x -s /dir \( SNIPPED \) -ls`

but I can also type as normal any routine "find" command and it'll pass it transparently to `/usr//bin/find` to execute.

Logically the script needs to identify the first arg after the dir name, and then test if it's:

- ... equal to `-noenter` and followed by at least 2 more args (in which case I know how to build the arg I need to pass to `/usr/bin/find` by knowing which args were before/after it); **or**
- ... equal to `-noenter` but not followed by at least 2 more args (= error); **or**
- ...anything else or dir was the last arg or wasn't found (= pass entire original args to `/usr/bin/find` unaltered).

I can do all of this except one thing - how do I code the part of the script that examines argv to tell which arg number (if any) is the `dir` argument?

My choice of shell is `sh` for scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to test for the existence and location of a specific argument, all you need to do is parse the command line and test each argument for a match with your "expected" value. So, you need to test each argument for the value `-noenter` and then print a line stating the position and name of the variable `-noenter`:

```
for i in `seq 1 $#`; do
    ref=`eval "echo \\$$i"`
    if [ $ref == '-noenter' ]; then echo "arg $i is $ref"; break; fi
done
```

Now the same thing, only the position of the argument `-noenter` is stored in `$mitsos` and the position of the argument before that in `$mary`:

```
for i in `seq 1 $#`; do
  ref=`eval "echo \\${$i}"`
  if [ $ref == '-noenter' ]; then
    mitsos=$i
    eva=$(($i-1))
    mary=`eval "echo \\${$eva}"`
    break
  fi
done
```

and now `$mitsos` has the position of `-noenter` or no value and `$mary` the value of the argument preceding `-noenter`. At this point, if `$mary` has the value `/dir` you *know* the next argument is `-noenter` and you may continue with your implementation of `find`, otherwise you use the system's version or print an error message. Finally, if you don't care for the position of `-noenter` you may omit the line `mitsos=$i`.

Comment: Thank you for understanding what I wanted! The answer isn't _quite_ right though. It assumes -noenter is valid in any position and just looks for it, but that's not a correct assumption (`find -x -noenter .....` should be an error). It needs to check the arg after the "dir" specifically, I think? I can probably figure it out from what you've written, so it's extremely close. Do you want to edit the answer so I can accept it, or?

Comment: That's not a problem, because this way you'll have a variable with the *position* of `-noenter` or no variable. So, you may check the value of variable `$eva`, where `eva=$(($mitsos-1))`and if the argument at position `$eva` is not equal to `dir` you continue with your implementation, otherwise you use the system's. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: That kind of works. I suppose given its a custom command script/mod, mis-invocation can be left as an edge case for now :) I wouldn't like to pass it to others to use, without a bit more checking for valid syntax though, but that's just my feeling :)

Comment: The method is right but I just found the eval statement is wrong. doesn't handle multiple spaces, or >=10 args. Based on yours, these handle the issues: `eval 'echo "${'$i'}" '` (output) or `eval 'value="${'$i'}" '` (assignment). Note ending+restarting the quote marks to include "$i" as a value instead of backslash+$ repeated. Still doesn't handle shell lookalikes on the command line eg `\(` or `|`, not sure what can be done about this.  Credit is all yours but if it's easy can you update to fix, or at least update to note the exceptions, so others get a better outcome if they use this answer?

Comment: I updated the answer for more than 9 arguments; you can just use curly braces if you don't use single quotes, which can sometimes be bothersome. The escapes will probably be more of the problem, and the pipe is most probably a deal breaker, but I'll see if I can figure a way around the first, at least.

Comment: I figure there's 2 aspects - get the arg into a variable based on its numeric index, and then safely requoting to pass to another function as an arg. Based on your hints, these worked very well:  `eval 'vraw="${'$i'}" '` to get it in a variable. I figured requiting is easier using single not double quotes, and just fix embedded single quotes if any (hence almost no need to handle pipes/odd characters, etc). I came up with this: `vquoted="'$(printf "$vraw" | sed "s/'/'\"'\"'/g" )'"` - try it. Interestingly quoting doesn't affect options apparently: (`ls '-lt' '/'` is ok) => safe for all args.